# Windows Authentication not working in Role Handler in VS Code and ASP.NET Core

Tags: asp.net-core, visual-studio-code

Odd behavior in VS Code using Kestrel.  In the Claims transformer I can get the identity.Name as the logged in user...me.  But in the Role Handler the claims come up null and no user name.  I would think if Windows authentication weren't working then it wouldn't work at all.  Works in ASP.NET Core 5 with Visual Studio 2019 but not in ASP.NET Core 6 in VS Code.  Yes, I understand that Visual Studio is using IIS Express and VS Code is using Kestrel.

**UPDATE: I have looked at the request in Fiddler and it seems like the second  request is actually being authenticated, I see a valid Authorization header in the request with Negotiate.  So that would seem to indicate that the Windows auth part of this is working.  I then see a 400 error which means that the request is badly formed.  I'll have to take a look at that.**

*Further update.  The real issue was authentication.  I created a service principal name and got it working.*

The explicit message in Fiddler is:
*Authorization Header (Negotiate) appears to contain a Kerberos ticket:*

```csharp
 services.AddAuthentication(NegotiateDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
.AddNegotiate();

   public Task<ClaimsPrincipal> TransformAsync(ClaimsPrincipal principal)
    {
        ClaimsIdentity identity = principal.Identity as ClaimsIdentity;
        string userName = identity.Name.ToLower();
        bool auth = identity.IsAuthenticated;
        string[] roles = new string[]{"admin"};
        foreach (string role in roles)
        {
            identity.AddClaim(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, role));                
       }
        return Task.FromResult(principal);
    }      


public class AuthenticatedRoleHandler : AuthorizationHandler<AuthenticatedRequirement>
{
    protected override Task HandleRequirementAsync(AuthorizationHandlerContext context,AuthenticatedRequirement requirement)
    {
          
        ClaimsPrincipal user = context.User;
        if (user != null && user.Identity.IsAuthenticated) {                
            context.Succeed(requirement);
        } else {
            context.Fail();                
        }
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }      
}
```

I'm adding the Program.cs code.

```
string CorsPolicy = "CorsPolicy";

WebApplicationBuilder? builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
builder.WebHost.UseKestrel();
ConfigurationManager _configuration = builder.Configuration;
// Add services to the container.
IServiceCollection? services = builder.Services;

services.AddTransient<IActiveDirectoryUserService, 
ActiveDirectoryUserService>();
services.AddAuthentication(NegotiateDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
  .AddNegotiate();
services.AddControllersWithViews();
services.AddScoped<IClaimsTransformation, MyClaimsTransformer>();//only 
runs if authenticated, not being authenticated here
services.AddAuthorization(options =>
{
   options.FallbackPolicy = options.DefaultPolicy;
   options.AddPolicy("AuthenticatedOnly", policy => {
      policy.Requirements.Add(new AuthenticatedRequirement(true));
   });    
});
services.AddSingleton<IAuthorizationHandler, AppUserRoleHandler>();
services.AddSingleton<IAuthorizationHandler, AuthenticatedRoleHandler> 
 ();
services.AddCors(options =>
{
   options.AddPolicy(CorsPolicy,
    builder => builder
        .WithOrigins("https://localhost:7021","https://localhost:44414") //Note:  The URL must be specified without a trailing slash (/).           
        .AllowAnyMethod()
        .AllowAnyHeader()
        .AllowCredentials());
});

WebApplication app = builder.Build();
// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (!app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseHsts();
}
app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseStaticFiles();
app.UseRouting();
```

Answer (score 0):

According to my test, it works well when I am using the Kestrel(.net 6) inside the VS(its same as run the application inside the Kestrel like VS code). The only difference between the windows authentication for the IIS express and the Kestrel is if you enable the windows authentication for the IIS express, all the request which come to the application will firstly need the authentication which means all the request come to the AuthenticatedRoleHandler has already been authenticated.

But if you use services.AddAuthentication(NegotiateDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
.AddNegotiate();`, the request will not firstly be authenticated, if the application find it doesn't contain any authentication relatede information, then it will return response to let the client put in the windows credential. This makes the AuthenticatedRoleHandler fired twice. The first one is authentication user name is null, but after the user typed in the credential, we could get the user name inside it.

My test result like below:

[image]

If this still not work at your side, please update the whole codes which related with how you register the requirement and how you use it.

Comment: Brando, I added the code I have in Program.cs.  Do you see any issue there? I'm wiring up the Requirement in AddAuthorization.

Comment: What is weird is that the Claims Transformer code is getting the user identity when the application initially fires up.  It's when the Authorization Handler fires with the Requirement is when I am not getting the user identity.  This code is almost exactly the same in IIS and works but not in Kestrel.

Comment: Could you please tell me which environment you run your application? Inside Linux or windows? Besides, have you tried to run your application inside the browser's private mode?

Comment: I got this working.  It turned out I needed to add a service principal name for the http service.  Now everything is working.

Comment: I am glad to hear you have solved the issue, I suggest you could post a new reply and mark it as answer, it will help folks who face the same issue could find the solution more easily.